# From JSON string that contains arrays to SQLite Android

Tags: android, arrays, json, sqlite

Im making an app that need to save some sensorvalues to a SQLite database. Im creating a json-string that has the following structure:

```
{  
   "forceList":[
       0.003,
       0.003,
       0.003,
       0.003,
       0.003,
       0.003,
       0.003,
       0.003,
       0.003,
       0.003
    ],
   "gForceValue":0.0,
   "id":0,
   "latList":[  
      60.66845333333334,
      60.66840666666667,
      60.66838333333333,
      60.66836,
      60.66833833333333,
      60.66831666666667,
      60.66829833333333,
      60.66828,
      60.66826,
      60.66824
   ]
}
```

and so on... the json string is a bit longer but the structure is the same.

The values that are of interest to me is the ones that are in the lists.
How can i put these values into the database? For example, i want a column named Force and the values from forceList in the column, and another column named Latitude with the latlist values in it.

Comment: Since you are using JSON, you may want to use [Realm](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#json) instead of SQLite

Answer (score 0):

The easiest approach would be the following:

- Using an online tool like [jsonschema2pojo](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/), generate POJOs that represent your json Strings;
- For example ForceList & LatList

Now, the next thing to do would be to get a JSONObject from your HTTP GET request results and use [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson) to convert the JSON string into your corresponding POJO.

Finally, as suggested by the comment above, trying using [Realm](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/) to store your data in your device.

I hope this gives you an idea. Let me know if you have more questions.